# How to unmask a function in R, due to name collisions on searchpath

Tags: r, package, search-path, name-collision

When I loaded package `debug` to debug a script with `zoo` objects, I got trouble: function `index` from `zoo` got masked by `debug` package.  How can I unmask `index`? In general, how to deal with these name colliding problems? We just do not use `debug` package with `zoo'?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Exported symbols are always identifiable with the `::` operator:

```
zoo::index
```

Hidden functions not declared in the namespace can still be accessed using `:::` (triple-colon), and example would be

```
zoo:::.onLoad
```

which you can see even though it is not exported.

Comment: On the other hand this is the reason why setting system<-function(){} does not magically make R secure.

Comment: thanks. I can temperarily set index<-zoo::index to work around this problem without changing my original script. It seems some packages just do not work together.

Answer (score 15):

You can detach the package which has masked functions and then reattach it. It will regain precedence in the search path:

```
detach("package:zoo")
library("zoo")
```

In the future, if you want to attach a package while preventing it from masking other functions, you can specify its position in the search path with an arbitrary large number:

```
library("debug", pos = .Machine$integer.max)
```

Answer (score 4):

Its only masked to you but its not masked to zoo so when a zoo function tries to use index it will still find its own index first.

zoo also has a time.zoo method so if z is a zoo object you can use time(z) in place of index(z).

Finally you can always refer to zoo::index to make sure you get the one in zoo.

Comment: thanks. time.zoo will work but I dont want to change my original script. And index(zooobject) reports error in my case. Apperently R doesnot know index.zoo should be called on zooobject.

Comment: If you load zoo after loading debug/mvbutils rather than the other way around  then the index in zoo will be the one you get by default rather than the one in debug/mvbutils.